# WMI values to array

Tags: delphi, wmi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Good afternoon guys!

I'm currently developing a small system management tool, very much in a style similar to the Windows 8 Task Manager in `Firemonkey` (`Delphi XE2`). At the moment, i'm attempting to create the CPU Core Usage tiles using `TPanels` inside a `TGridLayout`. I've added all my panels at designtime until i get the actual functionality sorted.

My issue lies with outputting the data from WMI into an array. I've already had a working version not involving an array, but i'm having trouble creating something more dynamic and less likely to fall over in different configurations. Here's the current code that's not working *entirely*;

```
Procedure CoreUsage;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  i : Integer;
begin
try
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
    FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation WHERE NOT Name="_Total" AND NOT Name="0,_Total"',
                                           'WQL',
                                           wbemFlagForwardOnly);
    oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    begin
      if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
      begin
        for i := 0 to 63 do
        begin
          CoreName[i] := FWbemObject.Name;
          CoreUsage[i] := FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime;
        end;
      end;
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
finally
  CoUninitialize;
end;
end;
end;
```

`CoreUsage` and `CoreName` are both global variable arrays of length `[0..63]` of the relevant types (CoreName is of `String`, and CoreUsage is of `Uint64`). The problem with this is that it shows the same value in all the panels as opposed to a per-core basis (which is my intent). It's almost like it's not going through the 0..63, and instead just retrieving the first value only.

I'm essentially wanting to assign each one to a value within the array as that would allow me to easily read core-specific details without needing to hard code. In the code i had working completely on my development machine, i had to manually go through and use something like this;

```
if AnsiContainsText(FWbemObject.Name,'3') then
begin
  CoreName[3] := FWbemObject.Name;
  CoreUsage[3] := FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime;
end
```

As you can see, it's hard coded to expect something but would be flaky in systems with 3 CPU's (in the above example). Obviously '3' was replaced with the appropriate array id, all the way from 0 to 63 (though 0 was looking for `0,0` specifically). The problem with this is that the CPU format is actually of `x,y` (where `x` is the CPU and `y` is the core). It's also not code that i'd be proud to use on the simple basis of it being unreliable. For example, the core name could potentially be `0,0 .. 0,7` and then `1,0 .. 1,7` for a system with 2 eight-core CPU's (16 logical cores).

Equally important, the code itself would have been a nightmare to maintain, but could have potentially been shortened down to a single `for i :=` clause and using `IntToStr`. But the problem of making sure it works would still remain.

I'm sure there's a perfectly possible way to do this, but i can't figure it out. I did try using;

`for VarArrayLowBound(FWbemObject.Name, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(FWbemObject.Name, 1) do`

and

`for VarArrayLowBound(FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime, 1) do`

but alas, no such luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I think, you have to use "while oEnum.Next" instead of for loop

Comment: try looking into MagWMI wrapper and demo

Comment: @SimaWB I wanted to use a `While` loop as that's what is generated with the WDDC, but needed a way to assign the data to a variable array in order for me to deal with it on a more "global" level. `While` is something i've not found need to use before (i prefer `For`) hence it was a lack of knowledge on it's usage :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your loop here:

```
if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
begin
  for i := 0 to 63 do
  begin
    CoreName[i] := FWbemObject.Name;
    CoreUsage[i] := FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime;
  end;
end;
```

You're simply reusing the same `FwbemObject` over and over again 64 times.

Try something more like:

```
var
  iCurrObj: Integer;
...
  iCurrObj := 0;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    CoreName[iCurrObj] := FWbemObject.Name;
    CoreUsage[iCurrObj] := FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime;
    Inc(iCurrObj);

    // Sanity check for future protection.
    if i > High(CoreName) then
      Break;
  end;
```

Better yet, make it a function that actually lets you know how many items in the arrays it populated. Here's a working (tested) example. (Note: Your example in your question won't even compile despite the declaration of the two arrays, because your procedure name `CoreUsage` is the same name as your array `CoreUsage`.)

```
var
  CoreName: array[0..63] of string;
  CoreUsage: array[0..63] of Extended;

function CoreUse: Integer;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  i : Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
    FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation WHERE NOT Name="_Total" AND NOT Name="0,_Total"', 'WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
    oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
      CoreName[i] := FWbemObject.Name;
      CoreUsage[i] := FWbemObject.PercentProcessorTime;
      Inc(i);
      FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
    end;
    Result := i;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I should always clarify that i randomly assign a procedure name when pasting code over here and don't necessarily use the one i did in the app. As for the answer, the first solution worked perfectly and is exactly what i was looking for. Many thanks, Scott!

Comment: @Scott: It's always better, though, if the code you post is at least compilable. It makes it easier for people to copy/paste to test. :-) Glad I could help.